# How to find multiple pairs in one oracle table

Tags: sql, database, oracle

I have a problem with finding matches in one Oracle-Table and I hope you can help me.

I have one bill-table containing booking data looking like this:

```
ID  GROUP  Bill-Number  Value    Partner-Number
 1    1      111         10,90
 2    1      751         40,28
 3    1      438        125,60 
 4    1      659        -10,90        987 
 5    1      387       -165,88        755 
 6    1      774       -100,10 
 7    1      664        -80,12 
 8    1      259        180,22        999
 9    2      774       -200,10 
10    2      664        -80,12 
11    2      259        280,22        777
```

As you can see, we have some bills that are containing costs.
Some time later, there is coming the counter-bill that is summarizing the previous costs. The sum of the bills and the associated counter-bill is creating a Value of 0.

Example: `value of (id 2 + id 3 = id 5*-1)`
or in numbers: `40,28 + 125,60 + (-165,88) = 0`

The counter-bills are containing a "Partner-Number". I need to add this information to the associated bills.

The solution should look like this:

```
ID  GROUP  Bill-Number  Value    Partner-Number
 1    1      111         10,90        987
 2    1      751         40,28        755
 3    1      438        125,60        755
 4    1      659        -10,90        987 
 5    1      387       -165,88        755 
 6    1      774       -100,10        999
 7    1      664        -80,12        999
 8    1      259        180,22        999
 9    2      774       -200,10        777
10    2      664        -80,12        777
11    2      259        280,22        777
```

I have to match the bills only inside a group. (ID is my primary key)
As long as the group is containing one counter-bill with a 1:1 relation to a bill it is doable for me.

But how can I find the matches like in group 1 where the relation is 1:N? (the group contains multiple counter-bills)

I hope you can help me - thank you in advance :)

Comment: I don't see any easy way to do this.  You might want to clean up your original source data so that you can avoid this problem.

Comment: Can you rely on the ID order to indicate groupings? Presumably not, but in that case you're stuck with [a Knapsack Problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knapsack_problem) which is not easy to solve in SQL.

Comment: Unfortunately i cant use the ID, the only assistance is that the Bill-Numbers are in the same Group - i am open for using advanced SQL here

Comment: @Limerick . . . This isn't really a SQL problem, it is more like a bin-packing problem.  There is no single solution (in general), and that makes it really hard.

Comment: Are your group small and are you ready to use brute force approach?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following SQL code, has been tested with Oracle 12c and 18c, respectively.  Ideas/steps:

{1} Split the original table into a MINUSES and PLUSES table, containing just positive numbers, saving us a few function calls later.

{2} Create 2 views that will find combinations of pluses that fit a particular minus (and vice versa).

{3} List all components, in "comma-separated" form in a table called ALLCOMPONENTS.

{4} Table GAPFILLERS: Expand the (comma separated) IDs of all components, thereby obtaining all necessary values to fill the gaps in the original table.

{5} LEFT JOIN the original table to the GAPFILLERS.

**Original table/data**

```
create table bills ( id primary key, bgroup, bnumber, bvalue, partner )
as
select 1, 1, 111, 10.90, null from dual union all
select 2, 1, 751, 40.28, null from dual union all
select 3, 1, 438, 125.60, null from dual union all 
select 4, 1, 659, -10.90, 987 from dual union all
select 5, 1, 387, -165.88, 755 from dual union all
select 6, 1, 774, -100.10, null from dual union all 
select 7, 1, 664, -80.12, null from dual union all 
select 8, 1,   259, 180.22, 999 from dual union all
select 9, 2,   774, -200.10, null from dual union all 
select 10, 2,   664, -80.12, null from dual union all 
select 11, 2,   259, 280.22, 777 from dual ;
```

**{1} split the table into a PLUS and a MINUS table**

```
-- MINUSes
create table minuses as
select id
, bgroup       as mgroup
, bnumber      as mnumber
, bvalue * -1  as mvalue
, partner      as mpartner 
from bills where bvalue < 0 ;

-- PLUSes
create table pluses as
select id
, bgroup  as pgroup
, bnumber as pnumber
, bvalue  as pvalue
, partner as ppartner  
from bills where bvalue >= 0 ;
```

**{2} View: find components of PLUSvalues**

```
-- used here: "recursive subquery factoring" 
-- and LATERAL join (needs Oracle 12c or later)
create or replace view splitpluses
as
with recursiveclause ( nextid, mgroup, tvalue, componentid )
as (
  select                     -- anchor member
    id            as nextid
  , mgroup        as mgroup
  , mvalue        as tvalue  -- total value 
  , to_char( id ) as componentid
  from minuses
  union all
  select                     -- recursive member
    M.id
  , R.mgroup
  , R.tvalue + M.mvalue
  , R.componentid || ',' || to_char( M.id )
  from recursiveclause R
    join minuses M
      on M.id > R.nextid and M.mgroup = R.mgroup -- only look at values in the same group
)
--
select
  mgroup
, tvalue      as plusvalue
, componentid as minusids
, ppartner
from 
  recursiveclause R
, lateral ( select ppartner from pluses P where R.tvalue = P.pvalue ) -- fetch the partner id
where 
  tvalue in ( select pvalue from pluses where ppartner is not null ) -- get all relevant pvalues that must be broken down into components
  and ppartner is not null -- do this for all pluses that have a partner id
;
```

**{2b} View: find components of MINUSvalues**

```
create or replace view splitminuses
as
with recursiveclause ( nextid, pgroup, tvalue, componentid )
as (
  select                     -- anchor member
    id            as nextid
  , pgroup        as pgroup
  , pvalue        as tvalue  -- total value 
  , to_char( id ) as componentid
  from pluses
  union all
  select                     -- recursive member
    P.id
  , R.pgroup
  , R.tvalue + P.pvalue
  , R.componentid || ',' || to_char( P.id )
  from recursiveclause R
    join pluses P
      on P.id > R.nextid and P.pgroup = R.pgroup
)
--
select
  pgroup
, tvalue      as minusvalue
, componentid as plusids
, mpartner
from 
  recursiveclause R
, lateral ( select mpartner from minuses M where R.tvalue = M.mvalue )
where 
  tvalue in ( select mvalue from minuses where mpartner is not null )
  and mpartner is not null
;
```

The views give us the following result sets:

```
SQL> select * from splitpluses;
MGROUP  PLUSVALUE  MINUSIDS  PPARTNER  
1       180.22     6,7       999       
2       280.22     9,10      777    

SQL> select * from splitminuses ;
PGROUP  MINUSVALUE  PLUSIDS  MPARTNER  
1       10.9        1        987       
1       165.88      2,3      755
```

**{3} Table ALLCOMPONENTS: list of all "components"**

```
create table allcomponents ( type_, group_, value_, cids_, partner_ )
as
select 'components of PLUS' as type_, M.* from splitminuses M
union all
select 'components of MINUS', P.* from splitpluses P
;

SQL> select * from allcomponents ;
TYPE_                GROUP_  VALUE_  CIDS_  PARTNER_  
components of PLUS   1       10.9    1      987       
components of PLUS   1       165.88  2,3    755       
components of MINUS  1       180.22  6,7    999       
components of MINUS  2       280.22  9,10   777
```

**{4} Table GAPFILLERS: derived from ALLCOMPONENTS, contains all values we need to fill the "gaps" in the original table.**

```
-- One row for each CSV (comma-separated value) of ALLCOMPONENTS
create table gapfillers
as
select unique type_, group_, value_
, trim( regexp_substr( cids_, '[^,]+', 1, level ) ) cids_
, partner_
from (
  select type_, group_, value_, cids_, partner_
  from allcomponents
) AC 
connect by instr( cids_, ',', 1, level - 1 ) > 0
order by group_, partner_ ;

SQL> select * from gapfillers ;
TYPE_                GROUP_  VALUE_  CIDS_  PARTNER_  
components of PLUS   1       165.88  2      755       
components of PLUS   1       165.88  3      755       
components of PLUS   1       10.9    1      987       
components of MINUS  1       180.22  6      999       
components of MINUS  1       180.22  7      999       
components of MINUS  2       280.22  10     777       
components of MINUS  2       280.22  9      777       

7 rows selected.
```

**{5} The final LEFT JOIN**

```
select
  B.id, bgroup, bnumber, bvalue
, case 
    when B.partner is null then G.partner_
    else B.partner
  end as partner
from bills B
  left join gapfillers G on B.id = G.cids_ 
order by 1 ; 

-- result
ID  BGROUP  BNUMBER  BVALUE   PARTNER  
1   1       111      10.9     987      
2   1       751      40.28    755      
3   1       438      125.6    755      
4   1       659      -10.9    987      
5   1       387      -165.88  755      
6   1       774      -100.1   999      
7   1       664      -80.12   999      
8   1       259      180.22   999      
9   2       774      -200.1   777      
10  2       664      -80.12   777      
11  2       259      280.22   777      


11 rows selected.
```

[DBFIDDLE here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=22f77806e7b67906ae446709b2ca760f).

Comment: thank you for your help, this solved my problem perfectly!

Answer (score 1):

`SQL`is idealy designe for a *brute force* approach to solve the problems (the only problm is, that for large data the query would *hang* forever).

Here a possible *step by step* approach, considering only one counter-bill in teh first step, than two in the second step etc.

I'm showing queries for the first two steps, you should get the idea how to proceed - most probably with dynamic SQL in a loop.

The first step is trivial self-joining joining the table and constraining the `GROUP` and `value`. A result table is created, whichis used further to limit already matched rows.

```
create table tab_match as 
-- 1 row match
select b.ID, b.GROUP_ID, b.BILL_NUMBER, b.VALUE, a.partner_number from tab a
join tab b 
on a.group_id = b.group_id and /* same group */
-1 * a.value = b.value /* oposite value */
where a.partner_number is not NULL  /* consider group row only */
```

In the second step you repeats the same, only adding one join (we investigate two sub.bills) with an additional constraint on the total value `-1 * a.value = (b.value + c.value)`
Also we suppress all `partner_number`s and `bills` already assigned. The result is inserted in the temporary table.

```
insert into tab_match (ID, GROUP_ID, BILL_NUMBER, VALUE, PARTNER_NUMBER)
select b.ID, b.GROUP_ID, b.BILL_NUMBER, b.VALUE, a.partner_number partner_number_match from tab a
join tab b 
on a.group_id = b.group_id and /* same group */
sign(a.value) * sign(b.value) < 0 and  /* values must have oposite signs */
abs(a.value) > abs(b.value) /* the partial value is lower than the sum */
join tab c /* join to 2nd table */
on a.group_id = c.group_id and 
sign(a.value) * sign(c.value) < 0 and 
abs(a.value) > abs(c.value) and
-1 * a.value = (b.value + c.value)
where a.partner_number is not NULL and /* consider open group row only */
a.partner_number  not in (select partner_number from tab_match) and
a.id not in (select id from tab_match) /* ignore matched rows */
;
```

You must proceed with processing of 3,4 etc. rows until all `partner_number`s and `bills` are assigned.

Add a next join

```
join tab d  
on a.group_id = d.group_id and 
sign(a.value) * sign(d.value) < 0 and 
abs(a.value) > abs(d.value)
```

and adjust the total sum predicate in each step

```
-1 * a.value = (b.value + c.value + d.value)
```

*Good Luck;)*